# Which beetle is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I'm curious to find out what kind of beetle this is. Google lens search suggested a type of longhorn beetle, but I am not convinced.

The photo is taken in Karnataka, in India

Thanks!!     [image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please [edit] your post to include habitat information and an estimate of the size of the organism. This information may be essential for an accurate identification. ——— If possible clear, closeup photos of the creature from multiple angles would also be helpful. ——— You may also benefit from taking the [tour] and then going through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

This is a beetle from the family of the "[longhorned beetles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longhorn_beetle)", since you found this beetle in India, I think this is *Acanthophorus serraticornis*

See the images for comparision (from [here](https://www.gbif.org/species/8624968) and [here](http://www.cerambycoidea.com/foto.asp?Id=613)):

[image]

[image]

There is not much information online, but some can be found [here](https://indiabiodiversity.org/species/show/256145) and especially  [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274537700_Report_of_a_large_Longicorn_Beetle_Acanthophorus_serraticornis_from_Pune_Maharastra) in this scientific article. The larvae of this beetles are considered a pest, as the bore into wood.